# Rewriting windowing raw sql into django ORM

Tags: django, orm

I have raw query, which I need to rewrite into django ORM.

Lets say we have model like this:

```
class exampleTable1(models.Model):
    value1 = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    value2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    value3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    value4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to compare filter of this model with number of occurences of primary key named `value1` in other tables, is there any way to do it in django orm?

Here is raw query I have as an example, I need to rewrite it into ORM. Thank you

```
    raw_query=f"SELECT value1,value2,value3,value4 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exampleTable2 l WHERE o.value1 = l.value1) AS count_occurences_table2, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exampleTable3 l WHERE o.value1 = l.value1 ) AS count_occurences_table3, 
    FROM exampleTable1 o WHERE name 
    LIKE '%example%' OR address LIKE '%example%'"
```

Essentially what it does is that it writes back parameters from first table and checks for primary key occurence in other tables and sends back count of these occurences in other tables of each line in exampleTable..

Comment: But based on your query, there is also an `ExampleTable2` and an `ExampleTable3`?

Comment: Yes, in these I need to check for occurence of primary key named value1 and return them together in one object if possible for each line of exampleTable1

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions